# mail: send email with attachment from commandline

Tags: linux, bash, email

I know how to send an email from command line (script)

```
echo "body" | mail -s "subject" my@email.com
```

Is it possible to send attachments from commandline (script) as well?

I am using `heirloom-mailx` on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: `man mail` didn't hint me a thing, so I suppose people do not use the standard `mail` in your UNIX or UNIX-like OS, or they just use another UNIX or UNIX-like OS.

Comment: I am using `heirloom-mailx`

Comment: See the answer in the duplicate I marked, it shows how to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simple way: to use `uuencode` (part of `sharutils` package). Any formatting or body text are unavailable. Just a email with attachement and custom subject.

```
uuencode /path/to/file file_name.ext | mail -s subject my@email.com
```

The complex way: to use `sendmail` and html formatting:

```
v_mailpart="$(uuidgen)/$(hostname)"
echo "To: my@email.com
Subject: subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$v_mailpart\"
MIME-Version: 1.0

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--$v_mailpart
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body>Message text itself.</body></html>

--$v_mailpart
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=file_name.ext
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file_name.ext

`base64 /path/to/file`
 --$v_mailpart--" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

in case with several attachments last part may be repeated.

Comment: The message text does not *have* to be html, you can use text/plain

Comment: @glennjackman yes, that's right. thanks for your note.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work as I intended: `uuencode /path/to/file file_name.ext | mail -s subject my@email.com` I get the email, but instead of attachment, I see the uuencoded text in the body. i.e. there is no "attachment" displayed, no way to "save" the attachment. The only way I can imagine is to cut and paste the text and run it through uuencode again.

Answer (score 14):

With `mutt` instead of `mail` you would simply call

```
echo "body" | mutt -s "subject" -a attachment0 attachment1 [...] -- my@email.com
```

Here, `attachmentN` are the list of files that you want to attach.

Comment: Does it allow to specify a custom From address?

Comment: You could use `-e` for setting a custom `From:` header, see also http://mutt.org/doc/manual/#my-hdr

`mutt -e "my_hdr From: My Name <me@example.com>" ...`

Comment: Works but with a strange result: https://imgur.com/a/GDwF2kn

Comment: I guess you need to configure your outgoing mail server https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_submission_agent