# Send backup by email with crontab

Tags: cron, email, backup

I use this `cron` job to do a backup of `/home/blah/` each day at 01:00 a.m. :

```
0 1 * * * tar -zcf /home/blah/backup.tgz /home/blah/
```

In fact I would prefer that **an email is sent to me with the .tgz file as attachment.** *(yes, the filesize will always be < 5 MB because my folder is very small)*

**Can I do something like :**

```
0 1 * * * mail -s "Backup blah" "blah@blah.com" --attachment=(tar -zcf /home/blah/backup.tgz /home/blah/)
```

(this is *pseudo-code* at the end) **inside the cron job ? What cron syntax should I use?**

Comment: Can't write a full answer but you can use `mutt -a` to send MIME attachments.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [mail: send email with attachment from commandline](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102092/mail-send-email-with-attachment-from-commandline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This following command worked for me when I tested in my machine.

```
echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a "/path/to/file.to.attach" -s "subject of message" -- recipient@domain.com
```

So probably the approach to follow will be something like,

```
tar -zcf /home/blah/backup.tgz /home/blah/
echo "Please find attached the backup file" | mutt -a "/home/blah/backup.tgz" -s "File attached" -- recipient@domain.com
```

I will save the above script as `backup_email.sh` and schedule the cron job as,

```
0 1 * * * /path/to/backup_email.sh
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9524359/1742825

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh! Unfortunately, I don't have `mutt` on the server and I cannot install it (shared hosting). Would you use http://stackoverflow.com/a/17422/1422096 then or another one ?

If possible, I'd like to use a one-line solution, so I could avoid creating a `.sh` script.

Comment: @Basj, the above link suggested answer works for me. But am not sure if piping will be a problem in cron if you want it as a single command.

Comment: `uuencode` is an older alternative to the (nowadays) more usual MIME attachments. It's a different process on the receiving end, but it may be the only thing you're able to do, though. Another alternative would be doing it as an `scp` to a central server that you control which itself has a cronjob that mails it off as a MIME attachment.

Comment: Ok @JoelDavis. What would you use as a one-liner code for sending an email with the .tgz file as attachment?

Comment: That's basically what I'm saying. That `uuencode` option may be the only thing you have available to you. I was just pointing out that it doesn't send it as a MIME attachment so you were prepared for that. Another possibility is to just ask the hosting company to install `mutt` for you. That's kind of an innocuous request that they may fulfill.

Answer (score 1):

I would install ZIP first, then schedule a backup.

```
zip system.zip /etc/* /var/www/* /var/lib/mysqlbackup/default/* && sleep 3 |  mutt -a "system.zip" -s "Daily backup as of $(date +%x)" -- user@domain.com && rm -rf system.zip
```

Then crontab it

You can also alias it in bashrc file, so you can execute the whole command whenever you like.

At the very bottom of your bashrc file, append:

```
alias backup='zip system.zip /etc/* /var/www/* /var/lib/mysqlbackup/default/* && sleep 3 |  mutt -a "system.zip" -s "Daily backup as of $(date +%x)" -- laith.alobaidy@yahoo.com && rm -rf system.zip '
```

So your crontab would be like

```
0 0 * * * backup
```

And you can run this backup at any time with your own `backup` command.